# How to align x axis with bars respectively in Combo Chart (Bars and Lines)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a combo/ bars & lines chart based on **D3.js**. The x axis domain contains min and max dates, and bars are based on values. But the last bar (rect) is outside the chart. I can bring it in by forcing it (manually) but it won't reflect the data.

```js
var data = [
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-13T14:00:00-0600",
        pop: 20,
        rh: 67,
        temp: 38,
        wspd: 7
    },
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-14T15:00:00-0600",
        pop: 15,
        rh: 50,
        temp: 39,
        wspd: 8
    },
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-15T16:00:00-0600",
        pop: 10,
        rh: 90,
        temp: 40,
        wspd: 9
    }
];

// Margins, width and height.
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Date parsing.
const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z");
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.fcst_valid_local);
});

// Set scale domains.
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

var y0 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 100]);
const y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.pop)]);

// Construct our SVG object.
const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g').attr('class', 'container')
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Set x, y-left and y-right axis.
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    // .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %H:%M'))
    .tickSize(0).tickPadding(10);
var y0Axis = d3.axisLeft(y0)
    .ticks(5).tickSize(0);
var y1Axis = d3.axisRight(y1).ticks(5).tickSize(0);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ", 0)")
    .call(y0Axis);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
    .call(y1Axis);

// Draw bars.
var bars = svg.selectAll(".precips")
    .data(data);

bars.exit().remove();

bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "precip")
    .attr("width", width / data.length - 50)
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", height)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y0(d.pop);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return height - y0(d.pop);
    });

const lineRH = d3.line()
    .x((d) => x(d['date']))
    .y(d => y0(d['rh']));

svg.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .attr('d', lineRH);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although an answer has been accepted, I'd like to let you know that you don't have to manipulate the `data` (as it might be fetched from an API as well) but you can play around the `x.domain()` as it's all about setting the right **domain** here.

1. Try using [d3 time_nice](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time_nice) to round off the time scale domains
2. Play around with [d3 time](https://github.com/d3/d3-time) methods to change the dates (there are a lot here)

Here's an example of using the second approach from above and setting the **x domain**:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
.domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
    return d.date;
}), d3.timeDay.offset(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.date; }), 1)]);
```

**Explanation:** This is offsetting the max date from the data by 1 day and so the new `x.domain()` would come out as:

```
(2) [Tue Nov 13 2018 15:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), Fri Nov 16 2018 17:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)]
```

which results in a chart as follows:

```js
var data = [
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-13T14:00:00-0600",
        pop: 20,
        rh: 67,
        temp: 38,
        wspd: 7
    },
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-14T15:00:00-0600",
        pop: 15,
        rh: 50,
        temp: 39,
        wspd: 8
    },
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-15T16:00:00-0600",
        pop: 10,
        rh: 90,
        temp: 40,
        wspd: 9
    }
];

// Margins, width and height.
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Date parsing.
const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z");
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.fcst_valid_local);
});

// Set scale domains.
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
    .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }), d3.timeDay.offset(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.date; }), 1)]);

var y0 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 100]);
const y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.pop)]);
//console.log(x.domain());
// Construct our SVG object.
const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g').attr('class', 'container')
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Set x, y-left and y-right axis.
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    // .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %H:%M'))
    .tickSize(0).tickPadding(10);
var y0Axis = d3.axisLeft(y0)
    .ticks(5).tickSize(0);
var y1Axis = d3.axisRight(y1).ticks(5).tickSize(0);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ", 0)")
    .call(y0Axis);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
    .call(y1Axis);

// Draw bars.
var bars = svg.selectAll(".precips")
    .data(data);

bars.exit().remove();

bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "precip")
    .attr("width", width / data.length - 50)
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", height)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y0(d.pop);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return height - y0(d.pop);
    });

const lineRH = d3.line()
    .x((d) => x(d['date']) + (width / data.length - 50)/2)
    .y(d => y0(d['rh']));

svg.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .attr('d', lineRH);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

I also tried with `.nice()` and a fun part would be to use the d3 time intervals within `.nice()`. Feel free to play around with those and let me know if you have any questions.

Also, I'm offsetting the `line` (path) by the **barwidth/2** in the line generator fn.

```
d3.line()
.x((d) => x(d['date']) + (width / data.length - 50)/2)
```

Hope this helps as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy data item that is a bit later then the last item

Here it is done hard coded but you can add it dynamic based on the date of the last item

```js
var data = [
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-13T14:00:00-0600",
        pop: 20,
        rh: 67,
        temp: 38,
        wspd: 7
    },
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-14T15:00:00-0600",
        pop: 15,
        rh: 50,
        temp: 39,
        wspd: 8
    },
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-15T16:00:00-0600",
        pop: 10,
        rh: 90,
        temp: 40,
        wspd: 9
    },
    {
        fcst_valid_local: "2018-11-16T01:00:00-0600"
    }
];

// Margins, width and height.
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Date parsing.
const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z");
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.fcst_valid_local);
});

// Set scale domains.
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

var y0 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 100]);
const y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.pop)]);

// Construct our SVG object.
const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g').attr('class', 'container')
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Set x, y-left and y-right axis.
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    // .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %H:%M'))
    .tickSize(0).tickPadding(10);
var y0Axis = d3.axisLeft(y0)
    .ticks(5).tickSize(0);
var y1Axis = d3.axisRight(y1).ticks(5).tickSize(0);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ", 0)")
    .call(y0Axis);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
    .call(y1Axis);

// Draw bars.
var bars = svg.selectAll(".precips")
    .data(data);

bars.exit().remove();

bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "precip")
    .attr("width", width / data.length - 50)
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", height)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y0(d.pop);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return height - y0(d.pop);
    });

const lineRH = d3.line()
    .x((d) => x(d['date']))
    .y(d => y0(d['rh']));

svg.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .attr('d', lineRH);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: It won't help if I have data from the API. it is a workaround but looking for practical solution. Thanks

Comment: @MaihanNijat: like I made the remark to add it dynamically based on the last value in the dataset

Comment: Thanks, It creates gap between line (red) and the right y axis. Also, the x-axis not aligned with rectangles. What is causing all this mess?

Comment: @MaihanNijat: you can't have the red line touch the right y-axis **AND** have a bar that starts at the last date and does not go beyond the right y-axis